# Can't query tasks

Tags: tasks, developer-console, query

I've tried executing the following query in both the Developer Console and the Force CLI and I get no response.

```
Select Id from Task where My_Field__c != null limit 1
```

In the developer console I get an error message:

> Communication Failure: No response from the server

Doesn't work in sandbox or production.

Is there something about Tasks that makes the function differently than other objects?  I'm able to execute similar queries on other objects without issue.

Comment: There is nothing about Task that makes it unique for SOQL. I presume you are running as a sysad and that you have field level security access to `my_field__c`. Have you tried `select id from Task`?

Comment: Yes, Yes, and Yes.  When I remove the where clause it returns as expected. Also tried executing a anyon apex SOQL statement and it fails as well.

Comment: 1) What data type is my_field__c? (2) Have you tried SFDC Workbench's query builder? - does `my_field__c` appear in the list of available fields, and if yes, what error occurs when querying this way?

Comment: @crop1645 Text(25), Yes, and ...  Still waiting (5 min +).  This is a very large org I'm working with.  Seems like it might be an internal SF indexing issue.

Comment: The error that was finally thrown was "Unknown Asynchronous Job"

Comment: suggesting perhaps that `select id from Task where my_field__c != null and createdDate = TODAY limit 1` would execute quickly ?

Comment: @crop1645 that at least returns 0 (because there were no items).  So i guess it is an internal index issue with salesforce.  I remember reading somewhere that you can request salesforce to index specific fields?

Comment: Yes, I have seen other posts where you can request specific fields to index by filing a support case.  I have no personal experience with this. That said, I'm not sure they'll index this field if the values are mostly null. Is there anyway you can use other fields in your query that ARE indexed to help SFDC shrink down the universe of Tasks to a subset that can be assessed without indexes?

Comment: Actually,  `!= null` will bypass all indexes and require a full table scan. It's a bad practice to use that in a soql query, if you have a lot of tasks, this is probably why it's going over the time limit.